# Running a ruby function based on data in a textbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my ruby on rails application, I have a textbox that, when someone pastes data, it gathers a bunch of data (e.g. does some web requests, etc.). I've gotten everything from the ruby function working properly just using some sample data.

What I'm trying to figure out now is how can I pass the value of a textbox into a ruby function? Is that possible? For example, here's my code:

```
<script>
  function doSomething() {
    var searchData = $('#myTextBox').val();
    <% helperFunction(<<How can i pass searchData here?>) %>
  };
</script>
```

I'm guessing if this doesn't work, I could always create a small form that posts the textbox input to a controller, and go from there.

Comment: Is this intended to run on the client browser? It seem unlikely you will be able to call your ruby function. You will need to post to an API that runs the function on the server.

Comment: Yeah, so this is in my view. The helperFunction actually runs and returns back data if I just use "sample data" rather than passing over any information like I'm wanting to.

Comment: Right, the helper function is being run as the template is being parsed on the server. The client will just get the results of that function, they won't actually be able to call it.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I get what you're saying. Makes perfect sense now actually. I really appreciate it man! So when data is pasted, I need to make it post to an API that returns the data I'm looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the way.

Comment: Yes, make an AJAX call to an API, when the text field triggers an onchange. Or you can even use a form and use in submit event to trigger the ajax call

Comment: Thanks guys! This did the trick! :)

Comment: So I created a form, and when the data gets pasted, it submits that form with the data pasted, waits 20 seconds (plenty of time for the data to come back), and tries to output the results of the POST request (the custom action) to the console. Seems to be empty. Is it because the template is trying to render the HTML for custom action that the form is posting to? Hope this made sense.